# What does 直打ち mean? also whats the reading?

Tags: meaning, definitions, computing

Can someone help me understand this 直打ち, as used in the following sentence:

`URLを直打ちしてアクセスされた可能性があります。`

(this is an error message in a log file)

My dictionaries have no idea what this word means.
As far as I can tell this means something like:

`"There's a possibility that there was a directly accessed URL"`

So 直打ち means "direct access", 
直 as in 直接 (directly)
and
打 as in 打つ (hit)

Also regarding the reading, i asked a couple of Japanese people and got told both:
じかうち and ちょくうち

any ideas which is correct in this context?

Comment: If would only pronounce it じかうち, and would only take it to mean "type directly", i.e. typing the URL manually instead of following a link/shortcut/favorite etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the prefix [`直{じか}`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%98%E3%81%8B&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss) ("direct"), plus `打{う}ち`, a noun form of the verb `打つ` ("to hit"), which in this case refers to typing ("hitting" keys).

Although I couldn't find a dictionary entry for this exact term, it's described in the entry for [IP直打ち](http://www.weblio.jp/content/IP%E7%9B%B4%E6%89%93%E3%81%A1) in the IT用語辞典 on Weblio, which confirms that the reading is `じかうち`.  This page also confirms that it means "direct(ly) input".

I think the message means there's a possibility the URL was typed directly rather than followed from a link.  Since this is in a log file, perhaps it indirectly means there's no [*HTTP referrer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer) information.  (In which case, it might show up even in cases where the URL wasn't directly entered, like if you use a "favorite" link; cases like these might be why it says a *possibility* of being typed directly.)